# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted

Tags: c++, stack, runtime-error

I am having trouble understanding why I am receiving an error here.
I assume it may have to do with trying to access a place that doesn't exist in the array? (I cant see where i'm doing that though)
When the program runs it will return the correct answer but then close with the runtime error. Would appreciate any help and general advice for avoiding these issues in the future. thanks

```
int len(char s[]){
        int len = 0;
        while (s[len] != 0) len++;
        return len;
    }

int isPalindorme(char s[]){
    int length = len(s);
    int limit = length / 2.0 + 0.5;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        if (s[i] != s[length - i -1]){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void main(){
    char a[] = "";
    cin >> a;
    cout << len(a) << endl;
    cout << isPalindorme(a);

}
```

Comment: You got it, `a` has a size of only 1, but you just read any old thing into it. You might think it surprising that C++ lets you do that, but it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` points to a buffer of only 1 byte in size (the null terminator), so the `cin` is trashing the stack when it copies data to that address.

You should use a `std::string` instead (or make your buffer a lot bigger).

Comment: thanks. so how would i initialize 'std::string' so i can receive it as an input from the user?